# Firebase tarda más de 2 minutos en cargar la información

Tags: jquery, nodejs, firebase

Buenas tardes.

Alguien sabrá porqué motivo Firebase después de realizar un loguin se tarda mas de 2 minutos en cargar la información?

EL logueo es correcto pero al pasar a la vista donde muestro información cargada con firebase tarda 2 minutos o a veces más en mostrarla.

Trabajo desde localhost, no se ha modificado nada en el código, no tengo nada de errores en consola y funcionaba bien hasta que comencé a crear mas usuarios para que pudieran acceder.

Los usuarios son creados de forma correcta pero cuando cualquier usuario inicia sesión hasta el que Yo utilizo como administrador y que fue el primero que creé se ha demorado hasta 5 minutos en mostrar los datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Pero sabes algo sobre el tema?

Comment: Con la información que colocas, dudo que lleguemos lejos. Preguntas a responder: 1. ¿Todo lo tienes en localhost o en un server? 2. ¿Qué tanto procesa las peticiones al servidor? 3. ¿Hay algún campo en particular que los usuarios utilicen que antes no era utilizado? Te recomiendo que hagas lo que te sugiere @MauricioAriasOlave así mejoras la calidad de preguntas y obtienes mayor calidad en las respuestas. Saludos y bienvenido a SOes

Comment: Ok modificaré esa cuestión, lo unico diferente es trabajo desde localhost y nada más.

Lo único que hago como especifiqué es un logueo por medio de firebase que es correcto pasa a la vista donde muestro datos obtenidos desde firebase y ya en ese momento tarda hasta 5 minutos en mostrar la información y desconozco el motivo no hay ningún tipo de cambio o algo adicional sólo comenzó a ocurrir de repente sin modificación alguna.

Comment: Qué mas necesitan para entender la pregunta? 

Indiqué el problema, desde donde trabajo (local), no modifiqué nada solo fue al crear usuarios para la aplicación.

Necesitan bolitas y palitos para entender o cómo?